# Access 2007 SQL Query Cleanup with a Union

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

So the column headers are:
hitl hitd lst ltype lnum npi dob midn fstn lstn hitn ssn address

The tables are:
SupHR CR

I need to do a union and join in one go. Some of the SSN are NULL as well are some of the DOB. Here's what I came up with. It keeps returning syntax error for the union. I'm sure i need to clean it up a lot.

```
SELECT suphr.hitl, suphr.hitd, suphr.lst, suphr.ltype, suphr.lnum, suphr.npi, suphr.dob, suphr.midn, suphr.fstn, suphr.lstn, suphr.hitn, suphr.ssn, suphr.Address, cr.hitl, cr.hitd
FROM suphr INNER JOIN cr ON (cr.ssn = suphr.ssn)
Where suphr.ssn IS NOT NULL AND((cr.hitd = suphr.hitd) AND (cr.hitl <> suphr.hitd))


Union
SELECT suphr.hitl, suphr.hitd, suphr.lst, suphr.ltype, suphr.lnum, suphr.npi, suphr.dob, suphr.midn, suphr.fstn, suphr.lstn, suphr.hitn, suphr.ssn, suphr.Address, cr.hitl, cr.hitd
FROM suphr INNER JOIN cr ON (cr.ssn = suphr.ssn)
Where ((suphr.ssn IS NULL) AND (suphr.dob IS NOT NULL)) AND((cr.hitd = suphr.hitd) AND (cr.hitl <> suphr.hitd))

Union
SELECT suphr.hitl, suphr.hitd, suphr.lst, suphr.ltype, suphr.lnum, suphr.npi, suphr.dob, suphr.midn, suphr.fstn, suphr.lstn, suphr.hitn, suphr.ssn, suphr.Address, cr.hitl, cr.hitd
FROM suphr INNER JOIN cr ON (cr.lstn = suphr.lstn)
WHERE ((suphr.ssn IS NULL) AND (suphr.dob IS NULL) AND (cr.fstn = suphr.lstn) AND ((cr.hitd = suphr.hitd) AND (cr.hitl <> suphr.hitd))
```

Not sure what I should fix.

Addendum: All data types are text with the exception of the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct syntax - which does not produce the error (the error was in the 3rd query 'Where' clause. Also, your second query will never return any results (IMO) because you are combining an INNER JOIN on the SSN fields AND requiring one to be null. Nulls don't play well in comparisons.

```
SELECT suphr.hitl, suphr.hitd, suphr.lst, suphr.ltype, suphr.lnum, suphr.npi, suphr.dob, suphr.midn, suphr.fstn, suphr.lstn, suphr.hitn, suphr.ssn, suphr.Address, cr.hitl, cr.hitd
FROM suphr INNER JOIN cr ON suphr.ssn = cr.ssn
WHERE (((suphr.ssn) Is Not Null) AND ((cr.hitl)<>[suphr].[hitd]) AND ((cr.hitd)=[suphr].[hitd]));
union
SELECT suphr.hitl, suphr.hitd, suphr.lst, suphr.ltype, suphr.lnum, suphr.npi, suphr.dob, suphr.midn, suphr.fstn, suphr.lstn, suphr.hitn, suphr.ssn, suphr.Address, cr.hitl, cr.hitd
FROM suphr RIGHT JOIN cr ON suphr.ssn = cr.ssn
WHERE (((suphr.dob) Is Not Null) AND ((suphr.ssn) Is Null) AND ((cr.hitl)<>[suphr].[hitd]) AND ((cr.hitd)=[suphr].[hitd]));
UNION
SELECT suphr.hitl, suphr.hitd, suphr.lst, suphr.ltype, suphr.lnum, suphr.npi, suphr.dob, suphr.midn, suphr.fstn, suphr.lstn, suphr.hitn, suphr.ssn, suphr.Address, cr.hitl, cr.hitd
FROM suphr INNER JOIN cr ON suphr.lstn = cr.lstn
WHERE (((suphr.dob) Is Null) AND ((suphr.ssn) Is Null) AND ((cr.hitl)=[suphr].[hitd]) AND ((cr.hitd)=[suphr].[hitd]) AND ((cr.fstn)=[suphr].[lstn]));
```